# How to post a notification in android with different package id?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Hello android developer,
Is it possible to post a notification with different package id in android.
For example:
An package id: com.app.a(app name: **A**)

I want to post a notification from app (**A**) which package name will be like:
"com.app.b" or "com.app.c" or "com.app.d" etc.

```
I have tried NotificationManager#notifyAsPackage. But it didn't work.

public void notifyAsPackage (String targetPackage, 
                String tag, 
                int id, 
                Notification notification)

Would you please let me know, is it possible or not or any better approach?
Thank you in advance
```